# Ttk Frame, Background color

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, macos-sierra, ttk

I'm using ttk, for my GUI. I know that it is also a very simple question ... I am trying to change the background color of the main window.
I tried to change the theme, because I am working on a Mac, (and Python 3.5) to avoid the problem with the theme 'aqua', which is the default.I've been reading about several solutions like these questions which are about the same problem... These are the numbers of the questions:

54476511,
38712352,
47327266,
23750141.

But, I haven't Solve the problem, yet.
Here it's my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



from tkinter.scrolledtext import *

from tkinter import Tk, BOTH, W, N, E, S, messagebox, END

from tkinter.ttk import Button, Label, Style, Frame



class Example(Frame):


    def __init__(self,master):

        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.master.title("Example")

        Style().theme_use("classic")

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=7)

        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

        self.rowconfigure(5, pad=7)


        self.txt_Pad = ScrolledText(self)

        self.txt_Pad.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)

        self.txt_Pad.insert(END,'Type your info here')


        btn_save = Button(self, text="Save", command=self.save_command)

        btn_save.grid(row=1, column=3)


        btn_close = Button(self, text="Close", command=self.onClose)

        btn_close.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=4)


        btn_help = Button(self, text="Help", command=self.about_command)

        btn_help.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5)        


    def onClose(self):

        self.master.destroy()


    def about_command(self):

        msb = messagebox.showinfo("About", "\"Insert a useful tip Here\"")


    def save_command(self):

        print('Your info it\'s save now')


    def open_command(self):

        print('Choose your File')



def main():

    root = Tk()

    root.geometry("350x300+300+300")

    root.configure(bg='#0059b3')

    app = Example(root)

    root.mainloop()




if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Any Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you getting an error? Is it setting the wrong color? What is the code doing, and how is it different than what you expect? Also, if the question is about the background color of the root window, we don't need any of the other widgets in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a style then apply it.

```
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *

from tkinter import Tk, BOTH, W, N, E, S, messagebox, END

from tkinter.ttk import Button, Label, Style, Frame



class Example(Frame):


    def __init__(self, master):

        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.master.title("Example")

        # create a new style
        self.style = Style()
        # configure it to the background you want
        self.style.configure('My.TFrame', background='#0059b3')
        #Style().theme_use("classic")
        # apply it
        self.config(style='My.TFrame')

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=7)

        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)

        self.rowconfigure(5, pad=7)


        self.txt_Pad = ScrolledText(self)

        self.txt_Pad.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)

        self.txt_Pad.insert(END,'Type your info here')


        btn_save = Button(self, text="Save", command=self.save_command)

        btn_save.grid(row=1, column=3)


        btn_close = Button(self, text="Close", command=self.onClose)

        btn_close.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=4)


        btn_help = Button(self, text="Help", command=self.about_command)

        btn_help.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5)        


    def onClose(self):

        self.master.destroy()


    def about_command(self):

        msb = messagebox.showinfo("About", "\"Insert a useful tip Here\"")


    def save_command(self):

        print('Your info it\'s save now')


    def open_command(self):

        print('Choose your File')



def main():

    root = Tk()

    root.geometry("350x300+300+300")

    root.configure(background='#0059b3')

    app = Example(root)

    root.mainloop()




if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

I left comments at the parts I changed.

Comment: thnx @Axe319, your answer, was correct, I just change one line un your answer.